# Could not find URL: https://conda.binstar.org/scikit/win-64/

Tags: scikit-learn, anaconda, binstar

I have anaconda installed.

Using Conda Launcher I get this error:

```
Error Fetching Package index:
Could not find URL: https://conda.binstar.org/scikit/win-64/
```

Something is amiss with scikit-learn and I cannot figure out exactly...is it missing on binstar?
Here are a couple of screenshots if that helps: https://youtu.be/hrcJyaUWOho

Also, 
Conda info gives me the following info (of which I am not sure what requests version stands for...)

```
C:\Users\kumar>conda info

Current conda install:

             platform : win-64
        conda version : 3.14.0
  conda-build version : 1.11.0
       python version : 3.4.3.final.0

       requests version : 2.7.0 (MY COMMENT - NOT SURE WHAT THIS IS)

     root environment : C:\Users\kumar\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3  (wri
table)
  default environment : C:\Users\kumar\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3
     envs directories : C:\Users\kumar\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs
        package cache : C:\Users\kumar\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\pkgs
         channel URLs : https://conda.binstar.org/scikit/win-64/
                        https_colon_slash_slash conda.binstar.org/scikit/noarch/
                        https_colon_slash_slash repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64/
                        https_colon_slash_slash repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch/
                        https_colon_slash_slash repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64/
                        https_colon_slash_slash repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch/
          config file : C:\Users\kumar\.condarc
    is foreign system : False
```

Comment: Might be a proxy issue, see the instructions here https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/fMHr4MAT-ZY

Comment: Welcome Kumar. It seems like a whole lot of trouble uploading a video to youtube and it's not very practical. You should put a screenshot as an image next time.

Comment: thx Julien...will keep it in mind next time...though it was not much trouble..-:) and I am not yet allowed to post images ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you get this `https://conda.binstar.org/scikit-learn/win-64/` url? It's a 404 error and I can't find any information/archive on that link.

Also, scikit-learn is by default included in the official repository of continuum ([here](http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64/))and comes bundled with Anaconda so I don't understand why you would want to set up an additional binstar repo for this.

I suggest you delete this manually added channel. This can be done from the Launcher itself clicking on "Manage channels" in the top right corner.

Comment: Hello Julien, I am not sure where this came from, the eror shows up when I start the launcher and also when I try to run some conda commands. Thanks for any suggestions on where I could start looking to troubleshoot

Comment: Go ahead and delete them. Then launch you python and try import sklearn and see if that works...

Comment: delete them from where Sire ? (sorry, fresh of the boat to a few things )

Comment: Like I had said in my original answer: 'This can be done from the Launcher itself clicking on "Manage channels" in the top right corner.'

Comment: and would u be able to tell me what requests version stands for in my question....and why it says 2.7 ? thx again !

Comment: and btw I am not trying to import this  again as its already there when I check the list using "conda list"..not sure where that custom channel came from...thx

Comment: requests version has nothing to do with the Python version (found other people on python 3 having something like 2.6 or 2.7), not sure what it means, you can safely disregard it.

My comment about import was to import the dependency in python to check it was working properly, not reinstall it. If you see it in conda list it should work fine

Comment: Mark the answer as accepted if your problem is solved to mark the question as closed please.

Comment: looks like I have angered the stack overflow gods -:) see the question at -2 and another question at -5...man I am close to geting baned probably !